# Lab for my Alt OS class and I'm unsure of this Linux Command

Tags: linux, xargs

I'm currently doing a lab for my Alt OS class and the professor gives multiple commands that you have to explain their function for. The one I'm stuck on is

```
find /home/ -user bob | xargs -d “\n” chown bill:bill
```

I understand that we are finding any items within bob's home folder and piping that to xargs which is delimiting something.  I'm just unsure what the "\n" portion is doing.  At the end, I understand we are taking whatever those results are and changing permissions to bill.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html? That would tell you what `-d` is for.

Comment: I have looked at the man page and the section for -d, but I'm not understanding what it means.  Is it just taking whatever it found in that home folder and terminating any that have "\n" and changing the ownership for those that it terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man xargs`:

> --delimiter=delim, -d delim
>
> Input  items are terminated by the specified character.  The specified delimiter may be a single character, a **C-style character escape such
> as \n**, or an octal or hexadecimal escape code.  Octal and hexadecimal escape codes are understood as for the  printf  command.    Multibyte
> characters  are not supported.  When processing the input, quotes and backslash are not special; every character in the input is taken lit‐
> erally.  The -d option disables any end-of-file string, which is treated like any other argument.  You can use this option when  the  input
> consists  of  simply newline-separated items, although it is almost always better to design your program to use --null where this is possi‐
> ble.

The `\n` escape sequence in C means a newline. The `-d '\n'` is typically used in `xargs` to delimite items by newlines - read one item per line. There is a significant difference as to quote handling:

```
$ echo "quote'not terminated" | xargs
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
```

vs

```
$ echo "quote'not terminated" | xargs -d'\n'
quote'not terminated
```

On [cppreference escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape) you may find C escape sequences.

Comment: Thank you! Those examples were very helpful, along with what "\n" is typically used for!